# Arch Linux installation (dual-booting with UEFI Windows)

Tags: arch-linux, mount, partition, package-management

I've tried VirtualBox, I've even given some unorthodox installation ways a go, like using [Architect](https://sourceforge.net/projects/architect-linux/) or Arch-Anywhere, but eventually found the vanilla ISO image to be much better and far more up to the task.

I'll go through my installation process step-by-step.

---

**Initial setup**

UEFI system with a single hard drive and a few partitions reserved for Windows (as unfortunate as it may be, I have to use it for work).

**Installation strategy**

1. Decreased the size of my last Windows partition, leaving 250 GB for Arch.
2. Inserted USB, used Rufus to format it and copy the ISO. Now that I think about it, I must've made two mistakes at this stage: a) used ISO mode instead of DD (appears to be an issue in one of the threads here); b) formatted it to MBR for UEFI and BIOS (but it's installation media, so it shouldn't matter, right?).
3. Rebooted. Went into the settings, selected my USB drive as the booting device.
4. Looked up `efivars`, but the directory didn't exist (unlike what the [Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide) states, and I clearly have a GPT system).
5. Created one partition for `/boot` and another one - for `/`. This is where the GUI helpers (Architect and Arch-Anywhere) failed completely, because somehow they'd let me partition the drive manually but wouldn't allow mounting directories. Also, as I later found out, `parted` and `gdisk` didn't work quite as expected either: both would leave unallocated space between Linux partitions and the Windows ones, and somehow both ignored the schemes I'd choose (FAT32 and Ext4 turned out as a single Ext2 partition for one tool and as a FAT32 and an Ext3 partition for the other). And while the empty space I can explain (confusion due to `print` printing information in GB and the actual commands using GiB for some weird reason), I have no idea how Ext4 would result in either Ext2 or Ext3. Anyway, that bit is not particularly crucial, because I can always format my system properly under Windows.
6. Where it starts getting mystical for me is this stage: `pacstrap`. No matter what I did to the `mirrorlist` on the vanilla ISO, it would fail connecting to repositories. Normally I'd blame Australia and its glorious Internet connectivity, but I've actually seen those repositories work within Architect and Arch-Anywhere. "Okay," I said to myself, "to hell with those libraries, it's an optional step, I'll try booting the damn thing."
7. So I've tried booting it. And `bootctl install` came up with something around the lines of "can't boot into a non-FAT32 non-EFI partition". That's where I lost all hope and started contemplating leaving IT and becoming a professional alcoholic or a full-time scrubber-wielder.

---

All in all, I'd just like to know where I screwed up. I've learnt the Beginners' Guide by heart, but it didn't help me, so if anyone has a functioning guide that actually explains every step for my particular situation (because I'd say *the* Guide doesn't), I'd love to see it. I'm also curious as to why `parted` and `gdisk` were being so weird.
I don't quite understand how "mounting" works either.

Comment: You should have bailed at 4. Try using `dd`, or if you don't have access to a Linux box, USBWriter, to create the bootable image...

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.
Should I create a separate EFI partition for Arch, or should I increase the size of sda1 and mount /mnt/boot there?

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#UEFI_systems

Comment: Removed my previous comment, because I found myself lying. The UEFI section in the article you mention (which I have read, obviously, not paying enough attention to it each time) is very clear and mentions utilising the already existing EFI partition (which I will have to increase in size, because the current one's 60 MB, for some reason).
My next question is whether I should use `systemd-boot` or `GRUB`.
Thank you very much for your help, sir.

Comment: I find systemd-boot to be much simpler to use than Grub, but either will work.

Comment: Alright. You've helped me out greatly, and I've managed to get it installed, sort of. This is what I get when trying to boot into the system: https://imgur.com/77NmSba
I've searched the web and tried different solutions, including changing modules load order with subsequent .img recompilation, however I can't get it fixed. Another thing I don't understand is why it's looking in sdb, when /boot and / are on sda. If I knew where that setting was, I'd at least be able to fix that to see what happens.

Comment: Your boot {loader,manager} is either misconfigured or, by the looks of that error message, not configured at all. Read the wiki page for whatever you chose to use.

Comment: I have followed your advice, so I've ended up using `systemd-boot`. This is what my `loader.conf` and `/entries/arch.conf` look like (I don't have LVM or LUKS): http://pastebin.com/6jAEdgUn

Comment: I've consulted the wiki and the various bbs's again, and I've come to the conclusion that an `options root=SOMETHING rw` is required for the bootloader to work properly. I'll try it when I get home today if I get enough time, hopefully that'll work. Still not sure why it looks for root in sdb, when no devices are connected, and the only one present, therefore, is sda. Anyhow. Thank you. How do I give credit to you for pushing me in the right direction and helping me out, sir? I'm new to the stackexchange system.

Comment: I've added a proper boot option with UUID, and it works now. Thank you again, and please let me know if I can somehow "reward" you for your help.

Comment: That's OK. Write up what you did as an answer and mark it as accepted, that way others that find this will understand what you did to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to thank [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) for pushing me in the right direction. At this stage, I'm sure I'd be able to install Arch blindfolded and drunk, but without his help I would not have progressed far.

**How I solved my problem**:

1. I've used EaseUS Partition Master under Windows to create a partition for Arch. I've tried using `parted` and `gdisk` on the live system, but I found them confusing: information on devices and parts would be displayed in MB and GB, however, the commands themselves seem to be working with MiB and GiB. When it comes to partitioning your hard drive, I'd recommend you go with the safest option at your disposal, because you might screw up your system otherwise. I've used `mkfs.ext4` to format the resulting partition, because EaseUS Partition Master only supports ext2 and ext3.
2. I've opened up the UEFI boot menu. My initial problem was that it didn't pick up the correct booting file on my usb (that was the case with USBs created by Rufus, USBWriter and `dd`), and hence the `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` directory did not get populated. So I had to manually add a boot option and navigate to the .efi file on the Arch Linux installation media. This might not be the case for you, but if your `efivars` is empty, you should not proceed with the installation, as you will, effectively, be running MBR mode (that's as far as I understand it).
3. Another quick note... If you have a machine running Windows, you will most likely have your EFI partition set to 100 MB. The [EFI System Partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition) page explicitly mentions the importance of setting it to 260 MB at the very least (if I remember it right). However, if you are partitioning your drive under Windows, like I did, you will not be able to do anything about it: to resize the EFI partition you'd have to move `C:`, and Windows won't allow that when you're running the system. I've searched the Internet and the Arch Wiki, and, apparently, 100 MB is just fine, so you can probably safely ignore that 260 MB instruction.
4. The Beginners' Guide (the current version thereof) suggests you `chroot` into `/mnt`, and then the next sections tell you to set your locale and timezone. Before you do that, you'll have to `exit` the `chroot` environment. And don't forget to get back into it afterwards.
5. I've used `systemd-boot` for dual-booting, because it comes with the Live CD, and it's very easy to set up and use. It will automatically pick up your Windows installation and your firmware interface, however, you'll have to create a configuration file for Arch. So just `nano /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` (or whatever you want to call the file) and make sure you properly set up `title`, `linux`, `initrd` and `options root=` inside it. I don't recommend using `/dev/sdxY` after `options root=`, because if you're running a UEFI system, its partition scheme will most likely change from boot to boot (a device might get called `sda` one time and `sdb` the other). I recommend using `UUID` to refer to your device. To find out what `UUID` your devices have, just run `lsblk -o +UUID`. Write down the `UUID` (or use `|` and `grep` if you are confident), and use it in conjunction with `options root=UUID=` inside your `entries/arch.conf` file. Don't forget to update `loader/loader.conf` accordingly.
6. You should be able to boot into your Arch system now.

**Final notes**

1. Make sure you are connected to the network before you install any packages off the Web. Run `ip link` to list available devices and then follow the instructions within Beginners' Guide to connect to it.
2. Always run `pacman -Syu` prior to downloading any packages. If you don't, you might "break" your system (or just fall asleep reading through all the `page returned 404`'s).
3. If you decide to set up a Desktop Environment, make sure you install the relevant video drivers. Otherwise you might end up with a boot process hanging at `[OK] Reached target Graphical Interface`. If that's the case, `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, log into your system as `root` and install the drivers for your system. `reboot` - and it should work now.
4. Most Desktop Environments' login prompts will not list root as an option. If you want to log in as root, refer to that particular DE's manuals or forget about it altogether and use `Ctrl+Alt+F2` for all your rooting needs. And don't forget to set up a user account, add it to the wheel usergroup and run `EDITOR=nano visudo` and comment out the lines that give wheel root permissions. A user account seems to be required to install packages from AUR as well.

Comment: A quick note: whether the firmware is in UEFI mode or legacy BIOS compatibility mode is determined by a firmware setting ("BIOS setup"). It is not dependent on the partitioning scheme (MBR or GPT) of the boot disk. They are related though: booting in UEFI mode depends on an EFI System Partition on a GPT disk. BIOS mode is normally used with MBR partitions, though you can use GRUB to boot a machine in legacy mode with a GPT disk.

Comment: You should not exit the chroot environment before setting the locale and timezone (point 4 in you answer). The point is to set the locale and time zone on the **final** system, so the name `/etc/localtime` should be relative to the root directory of the installed system.